# Accessing WSO2 BPS endpoint in WSO2 ESB showing errors

Tags: soap, wso2, bpel, apache-ode, wso2-esb

I am working on the WSO2 BPS 3.1.0 and WSO2 ESB 4.8.0, while i am consuming the BPS Server endpoint in WSO2 ESB (with help of PAYLOAD FACTORY & TARGET mediators) , i am getting the following errors,

**1.**
**The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is `http://localhost:9763/services/AddingPL/` and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.**

**And another error.**

**2.** `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><soapenv:Code><soapenv:Value>soapenv:Receiver</soapenv:Value></soapenv:Code><soapenv:Reason><soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">SOAPBody null for binding input.</soapenv:Text></soapenv:Reason><soapenv:Detail></soapenv:Detail></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope`

Please guide me

Comment: These errors are too generic. Can you please update your question to add the proxy config. AFAIU, you get both errors in BPS, which indicate that you are not calling the service properly.

Comment: Hi Isuru,Thank you , here i am sending my git hub url  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8413775. please guide me to solve this.

Comment: Hi, Can you try invoking the service directly from SoapUI? Create the SoapUI project from the WSDL. After that double check the endpoint URL in the proxy config.

Comment: Try setting the SOAPAction correctly using the header mediator before calling the BPS service.